# Understanding the rand() operation

Tags: c++

At http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/ , I read the following : This algorithm uses a seed to generate the series, which should be initialized to some distinctive value using srand.

What does seed mean and how does rand() use seed to generate the series?

Comment: The random number generator used by rand() is often not great, and you have to figure out how to transform its output to the distribution you actually want on your own. C++11 provides a better library in its `<random>` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very crudely, it is something like:

```
   int rand() {
       return last_random_val = 
          ((last_random_val * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7fffffff);
   }

   void srand(int seed) {
        last_random_val = seed;
   }
```

And the `last_random_val` is set to the `seed` when you call `srand()`. Hence, for the same seed, same sequence of numbers are generated.

Comment: It is a mask to bound the result so that a negative number is not generated.

Comment: @Programmer: It is to get the 31 LSB bits of the number.

Answer (score 7):

`rand()` uses a so-called [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). It generates not really random numbers but a deterministic sequence that *appears* to look random enough and satisfy some statistical properties. The seed is essentially the starting value of that sequence; given the same seed, the PRNG will always produce the same sequence. That is why you often seed with something that is not *too* deterministic, e.g. the current time (although that fails if you re-seed the PRNG in a tight loop or run the program fast enough in succession or parallel).

In most cases the PRNG in C is a simple [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). It calculates the next number in a sequence with the following equation:

[image]

*a* and *b* here are values that have to be chosen with care to avoid [horrible results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU). For example, for obvious reasons 2 is a very very bad choice for *a*. *c* just reduces the number to a certain range and is often a power of two. The seed simply supplies the 0th value.